# Currying lambda functions in python

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, currying, toolz

How can I curry lambda functions in Python. I am using [Toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, but it provides currying functionality for normal functions only and not lambda functions

Comment: lambda functions are normal functions.. Show us what, exactly, you're having problems with.

Comment: This should also work with *lambda functions*, since Python does not really make a distinction between them.

Comment: Since `curry` is a decorator in in Toolz, the q/a below may help.

Comment: @kazemakase Exactly what I wanted. Thanks! Should I delete the question?

Comment: Yes, please delete.